# How do I create a "More like this" block?

Tags: views, search

Is there a way to create a "More like this" block with the Views, and the Search API Solr modules?
I saw [this](http://drupal.org/node/1250304), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the recipe for search_api_solr as per the OP. Note: both apachesolr and search_api_solr leverage [Solr's builtin more like this feature](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis). It is, therefore, not available to *normal search*.

1. Enable some modules: search_api, search_api_solr, search_api_views
2. Create a Search server of the Solr class.
3. Create a Search index (or use the *Default node index*) and point your Solr search engine at it.
4. Create a new view on **your search index** NOT on Search index. 
   eg:

   `Show *Default node index* sorted by *unsorted*`
5. Continue and edit.
6. Reveal *Advanced* and Add a Contextual filter.
7. Filter on Search or scroll down to find *Search: More like this*.
8. Under *When the filter is not available* select *Provide default argument: Content ID from URL*.
9. Configure by selecting the *Fields for Similarity* that you want to determine *likeness* on.

http://drupal.org/node/1250304#comment-4870278

Comment: "9.Configure by selecting the Fields for Similarity that you want to determine likeness on."
I am interested in Taxonomy term likeness.How can I do that?thanks

Comment: @sokratis - If they are in the indexed in the search index (e.g. `default node index`), you can select them.

Comment: Also, note that the `search_api_views` module is bundled with the `search_api` module itself, not a separate contrib module.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything to create the 'more like this block', just go to admin/structure/block/manage/apachesolr_search/mlt-001/configure.

However, you can follow this [tutorial](http://www.metachunk.com/blog/adding-related-content-view-drupal-7) on how to create it with the Views module, but it's based on taxonomy terms.

Comment: Note: He is talking about using the Search API Solr module, not the Apache Solr module.

Comment: And for the normal seach module ?

Comment: I not sure about the normal search module.  The only modules I know that provide that is the http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr and http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr modules.