# Views Module: Related Content by Title Only

Tags: views

How to make a "Related Content View" but **only** by titles.

I know how to do it by taxonomy terms and such I don't want that. I only want it to be related by the terms in the titles of the articles.

For example, lets suppose I have an article with the title: "Stackexchange Drupal Help by Awesomeness People"

I want to make related content View with other articles having title with the words "Stackexchange", "Drupal", "Help", "by", "Awesomeness" and "People"...

I just want related content filtered with the words from titles, to show other articles with this same words. If possible excluding words with less than 5 characters.

I'm trying this for days now, I think this is impossible, or at least I can not do it.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Check this question - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38028/how-do-i-create-a-more-like-this-block

Answer (score 1):

The way I achieved this was by using the **Apache Solr module** https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr

It has a "*More Like This*" feature that makes it easy to show related content, see the documentation for that module.

Comment: Obrigado Andre. I will see this module, it appears to be very useful for the search function also. I learned yesterday Drupal.org uses this module in their website...